I have scala 3.4.1 installed on MacOS but version info from util is 2.13.12
I installed Scala 3.4.1 on MacOs with brew.
scala command runs and opens scala command line as 3.4.1 but getting version information as 2.13.12
scala --version
    Scala code runner version 3.4.1 -- Copyright 2002-2024, LAMP/EPFL

enter image description here
Welcome to Scala 3.4.1 (21.0.3, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> util.Properties.versionString
val res0: String = version 2.13.12

even intelliJ returns version 2.13.12 for
println(util.Properties.versionString)


Any idea?

scala3-compiler needs to be added for dotty.tools.dotc.config.Properties.simpleVersionString  as suggested by @Eastsun

By the docs of Properties.versionNumberString:

The version of the Scala runtime, or the empty string if unknown.
Note that the version of the Scala library need not correlate with the
version of the Scala compiler used to emit either the library or user
code.
For example, Scala 3.0 and 3.1 use the Scala 2.13 library, which is
reflected in this version


The "Scala runtime" is misleading IMHO as in OP's case you'd be tempted to say runtime is 3.4.1. It's the version of the Scala library at runtime. (The doc is at fault, not you :))

You can use dotty.tools.dotc.config.Properties.simpleVersionString if you want to get the compiler's version.

scala3-compiler needs to be added for dotty.tools.dotc.config.Properties.simpleVersionString
